# Ant exec task with included regex

Tags: svn, ant, exec

To be more specific I would like to run the following svn command from an Ant target

```
svn log -q -v --xml --with-all-revprops -r head | grep msg | sed -e "s/<msg>\([^<]*\)<\/msg>/\1/g"
```

The above command fetches the latest revision commit message by cleaning the  tags

and then I am trying to do the following but obviously it fails because the regex contains xml symbols with are written on top of xml code.

```
<exec executable="sh" failonerror="true" outputproperty="svnMessage">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="svn log -q -v --xml --with-all-revprops -r head | grep msg | sed -e &quot;s/<msg>\([^<]*\)<\/msg>/\1/g&quot; "/>
</exec>
<echo message="${svnMessage}" />
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encode string with some online html encoder.

```
&quot;s/&lt;msg&gt;\([^&lt;]*\)&lt;\/msg&gt;/\1/g&quot;
```